# Tap button to copy text?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How do I implement my app to copy a certain set of text for Windows Phone 8 when I tap a button?

E.g. tap this button to copy a sms template

Something like that

I want to copy text from the app itself

Comment: Some more details are required for stackers to anwser this. In example. do you want to copy text from the app itself, from a textbox. Or do you want to copy text from a sms message into the app. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean copy a fixed text (or a text in a TextBox) to the clipboard? Copy to another TextBox? ... ?

Comment: First web search hit for "windows 8 app clipboard": [Clipboard app sample (Windows 8.1)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Clipboard-App-sample-309ec122).

Comment: @user2386721 also - you have questions which were successfully answered but weren't marked as answer. If provided answer is helpful please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/17/31-days-of-windows-8-day-17-the-clipboard/) tutorial about copying text to Windows Phone 8 clipboard

Extras from it - assuming `selectedText` is text to copy:

```
DataPackage d = new DataPackage();
d.SetText(selectedText);
Clipboard.SetContent(d);
```