# How to enable copying item inside listview

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am making demo chat application and in that what I want is to allow user to select chat messages which is inside listview datatemplate.
Is there any way to allow user copying messages?. Also I want to display url inside message as clickable hyperlink.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ChatTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
       <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  >
          <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="1"  CornerRadius="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto"  VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"  MinHeight="30" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding message}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Foreground="Black" FontSize="14"  />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<ListView
 x:Name="chatListView"
 AutomationProperties.AutomationId="chatListView"
 AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
 Grid.Row="2"
 Margin="120,0,0,0"
 IsItemClickEnabled="False" 
 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChatTemplate}"
 SelectionMode="None"
 IsSwipeEnabled="True">
 </ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To set text : Clipboard.SetText("foo-bar")

To check if clipboard contains text : Clipboard.ContainsText("foo-bar")

No method to to get text  Clipboard.GetText() results in Security Exception

Comment: What I want is that I have populated listview with previous chats and now if user want to copy any of the chat than he/she should able to do that. By default listview does not allow to select chat which is a in a textbox inside datatemplate

Comment: use  tap event of listbox  and than  use clipboard.settext("listboxm selected item value etc") @zee it will copy whatever you want in that

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Also I want to give user flexibility to select like we normally do in word processing instead of copying everything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Windows Phone `Clipboard`.to copy the selected text?

This one would be helpful.

[Tap button to copy text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246109/)

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am working on Windows8.1 App so your link is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, I would copy/reference the selected bound object and store it somewhere else. The text of the message would be a property of the object, so that can be transferred elsewhere too or copied by clipboard later. So, for example, you're probably doing something similar to this already:

```
public class Message
{
    public string strMessageUuid { get; set; }
    public string strUserUuid { get; set; }
    public string strMessageSender { get; set; }
    public string strMessageText { get; set; }
    public bool booMessageSaved  { get; set; }
}
```

Then binding a list of your messages to your ListBox:

```
ObservableCollection<Message> obsMessages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
lstChatMessages.ItemsSource = obsMessages;
```

So, when a user taps on a ListItem you can get the relevant object:

```
private void lstChatMessages_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && lstChatMessages.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Message objMessage = (Message)e.AddedItems[0];
        //Now you can do what you want with the message, eg
        MessageBox.Show(objMessage.strMessageText);
    }
}
```

So, you could store the selected message in a new list of saved messages, eg

```
List<Message> lstUserSavedMessages = new List<Message>();
lstUserSavedMessages.Add(objMessage);
```

And then store the list somewhere. Or you could just get the property you want and store that, or just store the message uuid and retrieve the relevant message from the master list, or add a property of saved/favourited and then filter on that, eg

```
var savedmessages = obsMessages.Where(a => a.booMessageSaved == "true" && a.strUserUuid == "exampleuseridvalue");
```

Elsewhere you can display the saved chats to the user and let them copy to the clipboard etc if they need to, or have email functionality that will send the body of the message for them etc.

Hope this helps.

[Edit]

To add a url as a clickable link in the message just add a hyperlink button in your XAML to the ListBox's datatemplate eg:

```
<ListBox Name="lstChatMessages" Height="550" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <!-- Your other layout items here -->
                        <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding urlMessageUrl}" TargetName="_blank" Content="{Binding strContent}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Obviously you'd need the corresponding properties in your Message object.